# In an excel pivot table, how can I only select rows that has a particular value in it?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

Here's the pivot table I have :

```
Mat Cust    A   B   C   D   E   F   G      H    I   J
1   P       0%  39% 18% 19% 0%  0%  0%     24%  0%  0%
2   Q       0%  52% 21% 19% 0%  0%  0%     7%   0%  0%
3   R       0%  22% 19% 45% 0%  0%  0%     15%  0%  0%
4   S       0%  26% 32% 9%  0%  0%  0%     32%  0%  0%
5   T       0%  67% 9%  20% 0%  0%  0%     4%   0%  0%
6   U       1%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  99%    0%   0%  0%
7   V       0%  18% 17% 60% 0%  0%  0%     5%   0%  0%
8   W       0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  100%   0%   0%  0%
```

The individual row values are shown as a percentage of the row total.

So I want to select only the rows which have a percentage of greater than "90%" in it. Something like this:

```
Mat Cust    A   B   C   D   E   F   G      H    I   J       Result
1   P       0%  39% 18% 19% 0%  0%  0%     24%  0%  0%      N
2   Q       0%  52% 21% 19% 0%  0%  0%     7%   0%  0%      N
3   R       0%  22% 19% 45% 0%  0%  0%     15%  0%  0%      N
4   S       0%  26% 32% 9%  0%  0%  0%     32%  0%  0%      N
5   T       0%  67% 9%  20% 0%  0%  0%     4%   0%  0%      N
6   U       1%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  99%    0%   0%  0%      Y
7   V       0%  18% 17% 60% 0%  0%  0%     5%   0%  0%      N
8   W       0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  100%    0%  0%  0%      Y
```

What is the best way to do this? I cannot filter on all the columns as this would exclude some of the other subsequent columns that have values greater than 95%.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't see what the difference is between what you have and what you want.

Comment: @Andreas I do not yet have the "Result" column which I have showed in the second second pivot table.

Comment: Sorry about, I was using my phone and didn't notice that it was scrolling left <-> right.

Answer (score 0):

This array formula in M2 (under "Result"):

```
 =IF(SUM(1*(C2:L2>0.9))>=1,"Yes","No")
```

must be entered with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then filled down.

How it works:

The inner expression, `(C2:L2>0.9)` results in an array of True and False values, with True in the position(s) where the cell is > 90%.  Multiplying by 1 converts the True and False values to 1's and 0's.  Sum() adds the values up, and will result in a total of 1 or more if there were cells in the row > 90%.  Finally, the IF() checks for a sum >= 1 and produces "Yes" if so and a "No" otherwise.

Best of luck.

Comment: I used a Countif function to get pretty much the same result. So in the results column =COUNTIF(A:J, ">="&"'90%)